# Windows Phone 8 emulator on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I managed to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7, but from what I've read the emulator works only on Windows 8. Is this true? Is there any workaround to make it work on Windows 7, or can I only run the application on the device?